# Cannot load a file in Octave

Tags: load, octave

Apologies in advance if I get something wrong. This is my first post here (I'm sure there will be many to follow).

I have a file I want to load into Octave but it doesn't work. It is a plain text file (.txt).
The file is homogeneous and an excerpt of a few lines from it look like this:

```
0023,225.935,341.770,17.658
0024,225.935,341.758,17.782
LTAX17,228.152,353.935,17.665
LTAX24,288.304,332.878,24.074
```

where the first column depicts the name of the point while the rest represent its 3D coordinates.

Some of the options I've tried (but not limited to these) were unsuccessful.

```
x=load(text.txt)
error: scalar cannot be indexed with .
error: evaluating argument list element number 1

x=load("-text", "text.txt")
warning: load: file found in load path
error: load: empty name keyword or no data found in file 'text.txt'

x=fileread(text.txt)
warning: load: file found in load path
error: load: empty name keyword or no data found in file 'text.txt'
```

I have also tried simplifying the file, leaving only the coordinates and treating the file as a CSV but I keep getting similar errors.

Comment: are you sure 'text.txt' is in the current working directory? i.e. using ls, do you see 'text.txt'?

Comment: I've added the path of the working directory using >path and >savepath. Actually I get an warning every time I try loading a file >warning: load: file found in load path which I don't know what it means. Isn't the file supposed to be in a known path in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `load` is only for data files, not for text files. You might to use `csvread`, `dlmread`, `textscan` or `textread`. Check the [documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/function_list.html) as to the correct syntax for invoking each of these functions.

Here are the different approaches:

1. `load` does not work as you found out

   > > x = load('test.txt')

   ```
    error: value on right hand side of assignment is undefined
   ```
2. `csvread` works but converts all non-numeric values to `0`

   > > x = csvread('test.txt')

   ```
   x =

   23.00000   225.93500   341.77000    17.65800
   24.00000   225.93500   341.75800    17.78200
    0.00000   228.15200   353.93500    17.66500
    0.00000   288.30400   332.87800    24.07400
   ```
3. `dlmread` works in the same way as `csvread`

   > > x = dlmread('test.txt')

   ```
   x =

   23.00000   225.93500   341.77000    17.65800
   24.00000   225.93500   341.75800    17.78200
    0.00000   228.15200   353.93500    17.66500
    0.00000   288.30400   332.87800    24.07400
   ```
4. `textscan` works, results are stored in a cell array

   > > fid = fopen('test.txt');
   > >
   > > x = textscan(fid,'%s %f %f %f','Delimiter',',')

   ```
   x =
   {
     [1,1] =
     {
       [1,1] = 0023
       [2,1] = 0024
       [3,1] = LTAX17
       [4,1] = LTAX24
     }
     [1,2] =

       225.94
       225.94
       228.15
       288.30

    [1,3] =

       341.77
       341.76
       353.94
       332.88

    [1,4] =

       17.658
       17.782
       17.665
       24.074

   }
   >> fclose(fid);
   ```

I haven't done `textread`, but you get the idea.

Comment: 2. **>csvread** & **>dlmread** still don't work. I get **>error: dlmread: unable to open file 'text.txt'** but **>textscan** works the way you said. I would have never known to correctly specify the function's arguments. Thanks

Comment: `%s` stands for string, `%f` for float, and then specify that the comma is the delimiter in the file. It's all in the documentation (albeit the MATLAB one is more complete than the Octave one).

Comment: I could not get that from the documentation (if by documentation you mean `help textscan`). Yes, the arguments make perfect sense to me now. It only takes to see and example.

Comment: See http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/textscan.html & http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html.

Answer (score 0):

trying copying your data to Microsoft's wordpad and save the file as a ".dat" extension and load it into Octave. Worked for me, hope the same works for you, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

open a notepad
give this format

```
# Created by Octave 4.2.1, Sat Jun 03 19:48:46 2017 GMT <unknown@Asus>
# name: a
# type: matrix
# rows: 6
# columns: 3
60 30 50
20 45 65
24 23 23
23 32 32
23 65 65
34 54 45
```

save as file.data

open octave

```
>>load file.data
>>a
```